# RFC 5545 EXRULE Alternative

Tags: php, rrule

I have a calendar which needs to show recurring events.event overlapping is not allowed in this calendar. I have followed RFC 5545 standard and the this library to generate RRULE
[simshaun/recurr](https://github.com/simshaun/recurr)

Assume that I'm creating a event as follows,

```
DTSTART:20200201T060000Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20201231T060000Z;INTERVAL=1;WKST=MO;BYDAY=MO,TU
```

This is equivalent to

```
every week on Monday, Tuesday until December 31, 2020
```

assume that I need to add exception for every **Monday** and **Tuesday** in **June** and **July** and add another RRULE for every **Monday, Tuesday** and **Friday** in months **June** and **July** for year 2020

I found that previously there was another rule called EXRULE which is now deprecated.

Is there any solution for this?